# Incorrect Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined exception

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-data, sys-refcursor, ref-cursor

I've a spring data repository that call a procedure that is defined using named query. the stored procedure has two parameters that the first one is ref_cursor and the second one is in parameter. this is sp signature:

```
create or replace procedure proc1(out_pos out sys_refcursor , pTrans_ID in Number) is  ............
```

And also this is the namedquery definition on the entity:

```
@javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getProc", procedureName = "proc1",
        parameters ={
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "out_pos",mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR,type = void.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "pTrans_ID",mode = ParameterMode.IN,type = Long.class)
        }
)
```

And this is the repository that invokes the named query:

```
public interface TempReportRepository extends SwiftRepository<TempReportEntity,Long> {
    @Procedure(name = "getProc")
    public Object[] getProc1(@Param("pTrans_ID") Long inParam1);


}
```

When I call `getProc1`below exception raises :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined!
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:10093)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:5693)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:69)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: Not an answer, and not a good work-a-round,  but I got rid of the issue by removing the param names (and the `@Param` annotations), and then making sure the parameter order matches. It is not nice, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipselink
see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440078

Seems that you have to use the explicit creation of the StoredProcedureQuery using `EntityManager::createStoredProcedureQuery`

Answer (score 0):

#### Try ordinal binding

Named stored procedure query on the entity:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getProc",
            procedureName = "proc1",
            resultClasses = TempReportEntity.class,
            parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN,  type = Long.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR,type = void.class)
            })})
```

Calling function

```
private final EntityManager entityManager;
public PurchaseOrderDetailsRepo( EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
public List<TempReportEntity> getProc1(Long pTrans_ID){
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getProc");
        query.setParameter(1,eid);
        query.execute();
    List<TempReportEntity> result = query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```